# Nesting Functions-Python

Tags: python

I am having a hard time nesting 2 functions into larger functions, and so that the functions will open and read a file and print the outcome. There is no error, however the result shows up as `None`. Please let me know how I can improve the code. Thank you in advance!

```
import glob

#Read a result file and return a list
def read_results(filename):
    text_file=open(filename,"r")
    lines=text_file.readlines()
    return lines
    text_file.close()

#Give a list of results files in your directory    
def get_filename():
    filelist=glob.glob("./Data/*.*")
    return filelist

#Call above functions to get file names and read each file
def read_lines(filename):
    def get_filename()
        def read_results(): 
            print lines   

#main
function=read_results("./Data/GSM21203-GSM21215.csv")
print"\nHere's the lines of the text file:", function

#In order to use the strip method, it must be a str. Currently I am not using a         string.     Figure out how to do it

print"\n"

list_of_filenames=get_filename()
print"Here are the list of filenames:",list_of_filenames

read_each_file=read_lines("*.*")
print "Here are the contents of each file",read_each_file
```

Answer (score 4):

You should completely rethink how you're doing this.  Your code seems to indicate that you don't understand how functions work in Python.  For instance, this:

```
def read_lines(filename):
    def get_filename()
        def read_results(): 
            print lines
```

. . . creates three functions, but doesn't call any of them.

Read [the Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/) first.

Comment: Thank you for responding, I am a beginner learning Python and I am still trying to understand functions. Is there anything you would recommend?

Comment: Yes, I recommend you read the Python tutorial that I linked in the answer.